# Watch for current value changes in array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to watch for each item whenever It changes the radius and center, whenever It does I want to console.log the item index and the values

`let map = ref(null)`
`map.value.circles` is an array
When I use this watch function, it only displays the value once on load, I want to see it everytime it changes in my console. How can I do this?

```js
     watch(() => map.value, (currentValue) => {
        currentValue.circles.forEach((item) => {
          console.log(item)
        })
      },
    );
```

So when item.circle.center.lat() and lng changes, I want to console log it, not every item.

Whenever I update any item now, nothing logs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default in Vue objects (which include arrays) only trigger the watch when created or replaced. In order to watch for mutations of arrays/objects you need to include the `deep` option (`deep: true`).

You'll need to slightly modify your watch so you can pass in the deep option - I believe it will end up looking like this:

```
watch(() => map.value, 
  (currentValue) => {
    currentValue.circles.forEach((item) => {
      console.log(item)
    })
  },
  {deep: true}
);
```

Sources:

[Vue 3 docs about using deep](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/watch.html#overview)

[Vue 3 docs about using watch](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watch)

[Vue 3 Using Deep with watch() & Composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#watching-reactive-objects)

Comment: Tried using your solution, it wont log anything at all

Comment: OP is using the [`watch()` method in the composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watch), not the [`watch` option in the options API](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-data.html#watch).

Comment: @Terry the thing I have in my post seems to work when it loads first time on page, but it doesn't update any values which are changed, or whenever new item is added it wont log anything.

Comment: @Terry was correct - I updated my answer to line up with the composition api instead of options api :)

Comment: @vanblart, when I add deep: true, my app loads for 20 sec, when it loads nothing works. Without deep, it logs the items but doesn't log again after change.

Comment: To me that sounds like it's related to how you are updating map - when `deep: true` are there any console errors?

Comment: @vanblart is it possible to solve this with watchEffect?