# Vue component does not react on ref change from custom hook

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to watch the ref from custom hook, so I can use the variable in my vue component template, but it seems not reactive exactly inside of the component

Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
// useCustomHook.ts
const suggestions = ref([]);

watch(suggestions, () => console.log({suggestions}); // reacts on every change

return {
 suggestions
};

// VueComponent.vue

const { suggestions } = useCustomHook();

watch(suggestions, () => console.log({suggestions}) // does not react
```

Comment: Have you tried changing your 'const ref' to any other name? because it is confusing to use same name twice.

Comment: It is just a mock from my actual code, in the original it is "suggestions"

Comment: You are wrapping the `useCustomHooks.ts` in a function, right? Like in the Vue docs here - https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables#mouse-tracker-example

Comment: @BranislavPopadič Yes, I am exporting it like export default () => {}
Strange thing, this custom hook works well in another component (which is child of that component in example)

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. Especially since you have "strange" things that could only be explained with something unexpected on your side. It looks ok and cannot be currently reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

You are watching for ref that contains array. In this case you should pass the  `deep` option to your watcher. Or you can also use `watchEffect`. Here is a working [code sample](https://play.vuejs.org/#__SSR__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).

But basically what you have to do is this:

```
watch(
  suggestions, 
  // updated suggestions are automatically unwrapped, so you don't need to use `.value` syntax here
  (updatedSuggestions) => console.log('from vue component', updatedSuggestions),
  {
    deep: true,
  }
);
```

You can also find more information in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68116863/watch-for-current-value-changes-in-array) or refer to [vue's api docs regarding reactivity](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watch).

Answer (score 0):

I created a demo and it's not like you said.
[check here](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: I'm sorry but in your example you provide ref with number, but in the question the suggestions ref is an array.

Comment: I changed it to array, check  again